# Vue dynamic import with variable not working

Tags: vue.js, vite, dynamic-import

I'm trying to load my vue3 components dynamically.
I have defined aliases in the vite config file, when not importing dynamically this works fine and without problem.
But when I do a dynamic import, I get the following message:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: The specifier “@component/FormGroup/Helper” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Somehow the alias doesn't seem to be working when doing a dynamic import like this. How an I solve this problem?

`./vite.config.js`

```
import vue            from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import laravel        from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';

const path = require('path');

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
            '@bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components/bootstrap'),
            '@class': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/class'),
            '@component': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components'),
        },
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
    }
});
```

`resources/js/components/FormGroup.vue`

```
<script>
/**
 * Get async loader for component
 *
 * @param {string} path
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function getComponent(path){
    return defineAsyncComponent({
        loader: () => import (path /* @vite-ignore */)
    });
}

import {defineAsyncComponent} from 'vue';

export default {
    name: "FormGroup",
    inheritAttrs: false,
    components: {
        Helper: getComponent('@component/FormGroup/Helper'),
        InputField: getComponent('./FormGroup/InputField'),
    },
```

I tried to do a dynamic import in `resources/js/components/FormGroup.vue`. Then it does work, but then I need to repeat the same code for like 10 times, so I'd like to automate the dynamic import using a function.

Comment: Do you mean that `getComponent('@component/FormGroup/Helper')` doesn't work and `getComponent('./FormGroup/InputField')` does? FWIW, imports are supposed to be statically analyzed, replacing them with a helper like getComponent will naturally cause problems

Comment: @EstusFlask, it only works when I put the full file path into `getComponent`. But if I have like 10 component imports, how would I efficiently import them without repeating the same code over and over again?

Comment: `defineAsyncComponent(() => import` is a regular syntax for this. `loader:` part isn't needed. It's not obvious that you need async components at all, they serve a specific purpose which doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Which part? Async components are primarily needed for chunking, and it needs to be reasoned. You can commonly see them being used in vue router because a page is a separate feature that has a mechanism to load asynchronously, so it makes sense to have a chunk for a page. On the other hand, doing this for all components, including the core ones (which forms fields are) doesn't serve a good purpose

Comment: Okay I understand that I think. But my form field component has different components to display the fields and additional helper elements as well. when I render an input field, I don't need the textarea or select input to be imported as well, right?