# defineAsyncComponent with dynamic import string

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

i try to load a component with `defineAsyncComponent` the component name which should be rendered comes from the backend. I built the following function to load the component.

```
const defineAsyncComponentByName = (componentName: string | undefined) => {
  if (componentName) {
    return defineAsyncComponent(
      () => import(`../${componentName}/${componentName}.vue`)
    )
  }
}
```

During runtime i get the following error and the component wont be rendered.

```
CustomComponent.vue?t=1701850583908:194 Error: Unknown variable dynamic import: ../CustomComponent/CustomComponent.vue
    at dynamic-import-helper:7:96
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at default (dynamic-import-helper:6:12)
    at CustomComponent.vue:54:12
    at load (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2369:62)
    at setup (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2449:7)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158:18)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7327:25)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7288:36)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5683:7) 'AsyncComponentWrapper' 'async component loader'
```

How can i fix this?

UPDATE:

i change the function to the following.

```
const defineAsyncComponentByName = (componentName: string | undefined) => {
  if (componentName) {
    const importString = `../${componentName}/${componentName}.vue`
    return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(importString))
  }
}
```

with this implementation it's working locally but not in production. Also vite shows the following error in the command line.

```
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import(
) call to suppress this warning.
```

Comment: not sure you can load components at run time - SFC's need to be "compiled"

Comment: Same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606958/vue-dynamic-import-with-variable-not-working?noredirect=1#comment136824308_77606958 . imports are supposed to be statically analyzed. You can't just replace them without changing how a bundler works

Comment: @EstusFlask so what would be the solution then? Can you provide another approach for this usecase?

Comment: Just use import() directly. And you may not need so many dynamic imports at all, they serve a specific purpose

Answer (score 0):

I created a pinia store where all the dynamic components are getting registered

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const dynamicComponentsStoreId = 'dynamicComponents'

export const useDynamicComponentsStore = defineStore(dynamicComponentsStoreId, {
  state: () => ({
    dynamicComponents: new Map<string, any>(),
  }),
  actions: {
    registerComponent(type: string, component: any) {
      this.dynamicComponents.set(type, component)
    },
    getComponent(type: string) {
      return this.dynamicComponents.get(type)
    },
  },
})

dynamicComponentsStore.registerComponent(
    'CustomComponent',
    markRaw(
      defineAsyncComponent(
        () => import(`./components/CustomComponent/CustomComponent.vue`)
      )
    )
  )
```